How to visualize triangle using a software
How to visualize (using some plotting software) the triangle inequality,  $|x-z|\le|x-y|+|y-z|$, where $x,y$ and $z$ belong to some finite intervals.
I am asking for general way, for example, $(x-z)^2\le(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2$ is not satisfied for $x,y,z\in R$. Is there a way to visualize to conclude that it is not satisfied?

It seems you're asking two questions: (i) How to visualize the triangle inequality on the line, and (ii) How to see the analogous inequality with squares does not hold. Is that right? <> Either way, for the second, does the counterexample $x = -z = 1$, $y = 0$ (leading to the falsehood $4 \leq 2$) not help?

In the original revision you wrote: $(x-z)^<=(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2$.
Did you mean: $(x-z)^2\le(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2$?

Yes I am asking two questions. In general, gow to visualize them using some graph plotter. I know the analytic proofs. Asking for graphical visualization. Yes Martin, I mean wgat you corrected.

I have removed the tag [tag:geogebra] tag from your post.  I think that the tag is too niche to be of much use on this site.  Moreover, we generally ask that users not create new tags without first running it by the community.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/ .

Here's one way to visualize the situation on the number line for two points $x$ and $z$ at unit distance from $y$ if for all real $a$ and $b$ we define $d(a, b) = |b - a|^{2}$.


Can you please explain it further? Where those curves come from? And the vertical lines? What are we plotting against what? Can this method be applied for such three variables case?

The parabola with vertex $(x, 0)$ is the graph of $d(x, \cdot)$; the parabola with vertex $\bigl(y, d(x, y)\bigr)$ is the graph of $d(x, y) + d(y, \cdot)$. The formal triangle inequality $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$ is false as indicated by the arrows, i.e., the height of the right endpoint of the blue parabola is larger than the sum of the heights of the black parabolas.
